# splited payments type SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, invoice

Hi i have this tables

Sales

- id_sales (pk)
- amount

payments

- payment_id (pk)
- payment_type_id (fk)
- id_sales (fk)

payments_type

- payment_type_id (pk)
- detail (example:cash, debit card, credit card, direct credit)

how can i manage that on sale can have two types of payments, for example: a sale is $100.00 i pay $50.00 with cash an another $50.00 with debit card, and the tables record it.

do you think it's a better approach to put two payment_type_id on the table payments and have it like that and when is just one payment let the other in `NULL`

Comment: Why wouldn't you make 2 records in Payments? The fk to sales on id_sales ties it together. You don't need to add any records to payments_type unless a new payment type is added (ex: Bitcoin). Add an amount column to payments and now you can put 2 values (that add up to the total in sales). You don't want to make 2 sales records because it's only 1 transaction. You don't need to orphan records in payments ever.

Comment: Your table looks fine. For a sale with multiple types of payments, you add a row for each payment type - which is exactly what you have now. Don't optimize prematurely. Why do you think a different approach is "better"?

Comment: @SMor I disagree that the table is fine. There definitely needs to be an additional column to solve the issue. How does the current setup record a payment of $50 with a credit card and $50 in cash for a single transaction (sales record)? I know when I go to the grocery store and pay half in cash and half in credit I don't have to start a new transaction.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question as a question, if you put an additional column on payments for "additional payment types" what is the purpose of the payment type table? And what happens if you have a 3rd payment type? Or someone pays with a 4th? Now you have to modify your tables again (and your queries...). Better to put an Amount column in payments and insert a record for each payment.

Comment: And really payments to sales should be a many to many relationship. A given sale could have multiple payments and a single payment could be for multiple sales. And in the current format you don't even know how much a payment is for. There are many issues here with your design.

Comment: @JacobH thanks for the help man, make me understand better the issue, two records for each transaction its OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new "Amount" column to the "payments" table. Now you can store the split amounts with the payments.

When you have a split amount, you insert 1 record to sales and 2+ records to payments, one for each payment per sales transaction. You don't need to put null records into payments, only a record for each legitimate payment. You can now even put multiple payments of the same type if someone paid with 2 different credit cards etc.

All the payments relate to 1 sales transaction (id_sales). Each payment has 1 payment type and you don't have to put in blank records or NULL into any column.

Comment: Good answer.  This scenario, and thousands like it would be a lot easier to explain if everybody understood double qentry bookkeeping.